# Auto generate invoices for all clients - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Ruby on Rails app and i want to generate invoices for all clients at once , there is an one_to_many association between tables . My client table is named Clientpf and the invoice table is named Factpf, i have a an generate method in the Factpf model that looks like this

## Factpf model method

```
def self.generate(client)
@clientpfs = client
@clientpfs.each do |clientpf|
factpf.create!
sold = clientpf.sold
tt = clientpf.ab
rez = tt * 3
if sold > 0 and rez > sold
factpf.suma  = clientpf.ab
factpf.data = Time.now
factpf.save!
end
end
end
```

and the call method in the factpf_controller looks like this

## Facptpf_controller call method

```
def generate
client  = Clientpf.all
Factpf.generate(params[:client])
redirect_to root_url, notice: "Facturile lunare au fost emise."
end
```

an the error that i have looks like this ,

Couldn't find Factpf with id=generate

Extracted source (around line #88):
86
87
88
89
90
91

```
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_factpf
  @factpf = Factpf.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
```

Rails.root: /home/dbdominet

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/factpfs_controller.rb:88:in `set_factpf'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"generate"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use create/build to create related entity

Example:

```
client = Clientpf.find params[:client_id]
factpf = client.factpfs.create suma: clientpf.ab, data: Time.now
```

For more information, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html